# Use Jackson deserializer to read child JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a Spring Boot application with Jackson dependency, and a Service with this code:

```
Dto dto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Dto.class);
```

I have a JSON similar to this one:

```
{
    "meta": {
    ...
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": {"raw": "1"},
            "name": {"raw": "Hello World"}
            "number": {"raw": 7.5}
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have a Java class like this one:

```
public class Dto {
    private AnotherDto meta;
    private List<ResultDto> results;
    // getters/setters
}
```

```
public class ResultDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Wrapper<String> id;

    // More fields and getters/setters
}
```

Then, I have a generic Wrapper class like this one (idea from Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization ):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = WrapperDeserializer.class)
public class Wrapper<T> {
    T value;
    // getters/setters
}
```

Lastly, I have the next deserializer:

```
public class WrapperDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Wrapper<?>> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    private JavaType type;

    @Override
    public Wrapper<?> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        Wrapper<?> wrapper = new Wrapper<>();
        wrapper.setValue(deserializationContext.readValue(jsonParser, type));
        return wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext deserializationContext, BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        this.type = beanProperty.getType().containedType(0);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The main doubt is, how I can access to jsonParser object in order to get the child JSON information? In this case, I would like to access `{"raw": "1"}`, so I could get the child into *raw* key and get the proper value, so ID "1" would be saved in final Java object.

I wouldn't want to make `deserializationContext.readValue(jsonParser, type)` as in this example, because it would throw this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source:
```

Because `{"raw": "1"}` is not a valid String. I would want to have only the "1" value.

Comment: If you are writing standalone, application-based Java (ie. you implement a `public static void main(String[])` that is your entry point, the typical use pattern is to create an `ObjectMapper` instance which will create and manage the `JSONParser` instance for you (since it requires extensive configuration).  See the Jackson javadoc for details.   If you are using a J2EE / container / web-based technologies, this will be the wrong approach and you need to give us more information.

Comment: That said, this is not a properly focused / asked question here.  Open-ended "just wondering how do I....?" will likely be closed - you need to show us that made some effort, attempted to answer your own question first, you've tried some concrete things, list code relevant to your actual question, show errors, etc.   Please review [ask].

Comment: I have indicated the partial solution I have analyzed, but I don't know how to manage the JsonParser class. There is no error as it is clear the readValue function in the deserialize part will fail, as JSON has {"raw": "1"} instead of "1" wich will be the normal case. I think the doubt is valid and concrete, but I could add more information if needed.

Comment: This is not concrete.   A "Concrete" doubt means you ran it, it didn't work, and you gave us enough information so that we can take your code, also run it, and verify that it does not work.  Not "I'm pretty sure if I ran this code it would not work".   A "Concrete" example would include the information I asked you for above, and would include /configuration of the context and binding of the serializable type/.   Can we run the code you list above as is and reproduce your results?  No, we cannot.  Please actually look at [ask] like I indicated you should, and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Okey, I have edited the question, including some context and the error raised, with the expected result too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close. The main issue is that you used the field name `value` where it should be `raw`. Also, the `WrapperDeserializer` is not required.

All the code is as you have it besides the following:

**Wrapper.java**

```
public class Wrapper<T> {

    T raw;
  
    // getters, setters & toString()
}
```

**main**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"results\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "            \"id\": {\"raw\": \"1\"},\r\n" + 
                "            \"name\": {\"raw\": \"Hello World\"},\r\n" + 
                "            \"number\": {\"raw\": 7.5}\r\n" + 
                "        }\r\n" + 
                "    ]\r\n" + 
                "}";
        
        Dto readValue = objectMapper.readValue(json, Dto.class);
        
        System.out.println(readValue);
}
```

**Output**

```
Dto [results=[ResultDto [id=Wrapper [raw=1], name=Wrapper [raw=Hello World], number=Wrapper [raw=7]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so obsessed with the use of a deserialize that I dind't consider it wasn't actually necessary. That works perfectly.